# Memcache not updated when new contents posted on Drupal

Tags: drupal-7, memcached

I have a drupal-7 application which has memcache configured. When ever i update any contents through admin panel, The new contents like Url alias, images etc are not getting updated to memcache and it servers the same old cache. Below is my configuration settings

```
### Memcache Settings ###

 $conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/contrib/memcache/memcache.inc';
 $conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';
 $conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';

 $conf['memcache_servers'] = array(
   '10.10.12.161:11211' => 'default');

 $conf['memcache_bins'] = array(
   'cache' => 'default'
 );
```

Would be great if some one can guide me to fix it.

Thanks,

Swaroop.

Comment: Using form_alter add memcache clear code in submit handler.

Comment: Hi Prashant can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Use form_alter and add custom submit handler. In custom submit handler after you update node/comment/config delete Memcache.